# With JavaEE6, do we still need Spring, Hibernate or other frameworks?

Tags: java, frameworks, jakarta-ee, java-ee-6

Question as stated on title. Thank you.

Comment: @Closers Please explain what is subjective or argumentative? There is nothing like this in my answer IMHO.

Comment: Please have more consideration of who you are writing the question for.

Answer (score 4):

It's not mandatory at all to use Spring when you have a Java EE 6 server. Of course, if you need specific Spring features then it makes sense but otherwise...

Don't misinterpret me. Spring is a cool container and it did a great job in bringing Java EE to where it is now but in most cases Java EE 6 is good enough.